# HTML doc for scalable viewing and auto resizing

Tags: html

I am trying to get an email invite out with basic HTML5, no JS and as simple as me.

I got the following to work to a degree. I have 3 JPGs in top row and 2 in next then text. Everything resizes until it gets really small. My iPad for example puts the last JPG in the top row in the next. etc.

I reduced the percentages of width to add up to less than 100% total per the row and that helps to a certain point. But when I reduce it to maybe phone screen size it does the overflow jump.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      p { color: #000000 }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body lang="en-US" text="#000000" dir="ltr" style="background: transparent">
    <span class="sd-abs-pos" style="position: relative">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,data"
           name="a1" width="16.66%" border="0">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,data"
           name="a2" width="16.66%" border="0">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,data"
           name="a3" width="33%" border="0">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,data"
           name="a4" width="33%" border="0">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,data"
           name="b1" width="33%" border="0" style="margin-left: 16.66%">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,data"
           name="b2" width="33%" border="0">
    </span>
    <p align="center" style="margin-top: 3vw; margin-bottom: 5vw">
      <font face="Baoli SC"><font style="font-size: 5vw">
        100 Schools<br>
        Invites you to the opening of it's<br>
        50<sup>th</sup>
        School in<br>
        etc<br>
        November 28, 2016 
        </font></font>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure without a working example, but one of the most common reasons for this is white space between the elements.

Try either putting the image elements in a line with no spaces

```
<img src="" width="33%" /><img src="" width="33%" /><img src="" width="33%" />
```

Or using comments to "hide" the white space:

```
<img src="" width="33%" /><!--
--><img src="" width="33%" /><!--
--><img src="" width="33%" />
```

This occurs because although the white space is collapsed, it will leave a single space. Since your elements leave 1% spare (33% * 3 = 99%), if those spaces are less than 1% of the width, it will display correctly. However on small screens where the spaces take up more than 1% of the width, they will push the last element to a new line.

Example:

```css
.box{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
With white-space
<div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
Without white-space (inline)
<div>
  <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
</div>
Without white-space (comments)
<div>
  <div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that did it and butted the imgs properly. That margin should have tipped me off